# Exception in setup sorm

Tags: mysql, scala, exception, playframework-2.3, sorm

I cannot initialize project with sorm framework with mysql. I have scala 2.10.4. I have configured my mysql database in application.conf. I add DB object in my models package:

```
package models

import sorm._

object DB extends Instance(
    entities = Set(Entity[User]()),
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
    user = "root"
)
```

but I have received this exception

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class models.DB$]
```

Help me please who know what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your object should be in package `models`. Either the code sample is not complete there, or you should have to add `package models` before you object declaration.

```scala
package models

import sorm._

object DB ...
```

Comment: So you need to update the code in you question to make it clear.

Comment: In activator/SBT, type `console` (like `run` for the run task), then in REPL console type `models.DB`, should print the object as string if available.

Comment: Thanks to your advice I find my error, if I create table in lowercase it's works